# Any way to limit elasticsearch to only match the closest token? [Edge n-gram, Fuzziness]

Tags: elasticsearch

Using Tokenizer, Fuzziness and Edge n-gram I have three documents:

- "Star Trek I"
- "Star Trekian"
- "Star Trakian: A Star Trek Documentary"

Searching "**Star Trek**" with fuzziness gives "**Star Trekian**" a higher score than "**Star Trek**" because of additional tokens that match "**Trek**" (=> "**Treki**"). Is the best way to combat this to match additionally with less or no fuzziness?

Furthermore "**Star Trakian: A Star Trek Documentary**" gets an even higher score because it matches "**Trak**" and "**Trek**". Is there a way to match only the best token or any other method to score it the same as "**Star Trek I**" (because both contain "**Star Trek**")?

Edit:

Mappings & Settings:

```
PUT /stackoverflow
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "edge_n_gram": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": "1",
          "max_gram": "50"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            "edge_n_gram"
          ],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "autocomplete"
        },
        "autocomplete_search": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "char_group"
        },
        "full_word": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "char_group"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "standard"
        },
        "char_group": {
          "type": "char_group",
          "tokenize_on_chars": [
            "whitespace",
            "-",
            "."
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "search_field_full": {
        "type": "text",
        "similarity": "boolean",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "text",
            "similarity": "boolean",
            "analyzer": "full_word",
            "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": "autocomplete",
        "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Documents:

```
POST stackoverflow/_doc/
{
  "search_field_full": "Star Trek I"
}

POST stackoverflow/_doc/
{
  "search_field_full": "Star Trakian: A Star Trek Documentary"
}

POST stackoverflow/_doc/
{
  "search_field_full": "Star Trekian"
}
```

Query:

```
GET stackoverflow/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
              "search_field_full"
            ],
            "fuzziness": "AUTO:4,7",
            "max_expansions": 500,
            "minimum_should_match": 2,
            "operator": "or",
            "query": "Star Trek",
            "type": "best_fields"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
              "search_field_full.raw^30"
            ],
            "fuzziness": 0,
            "operator": "or",
            "query": "Star Trek",
            "type": "best_fields"
          }
        },
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "fields": [
              "search_field_full.raw^20"
            ],
            "fuzziness": 1,
            "operator": "or",
            "query": "Star Trek",
            "type": "best_fields"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: would you mind sharing your mapping, sample docs and query so that I can easily repro your issue

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I added them to my post.